# How to bind/relate a object reference with new[] (array)?

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, new-operator

It's common to have reference bound to a simple object as,

```
T& t = *new T;
```

But, how to relate a reference with the output of `new[]` ?

```
T& ??? = *new T[size];
```

[Note: [Here](http://www.ideone.com/5M5Rb) is one possible way, but I think there should be some better way out, which gives the effect of array.]

**Edit**: This question is not about good/bad coding practice or if this is common/uncommon to use. I wanted to know if this is syntactically possible or not?

Comment: It's certainly not common, nor should it be. Perhaps you meant dereferencing a pointer variable, as opposed to a new expression directly?

Comment: May be less common, I have seen this being used. One popular example can be from Bjarne's web page: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#new-java

Comment: I agree that's not common, for sure, but how are you intending to use the newly-allocated array? I can't fathom what that would even look like. I would just use a pointer and access that pointer the same as an array.

Comment: Actually, on that page, Bjarne is basically saying *not* to do that.

Comment: @iammilind: That example is specifically called out as an anti-pattern; an example of what _not_ to do.

Comment: @Jim, he is suggesting not use `new` in general compared to automatic objects. Just that he has given example as specified above (and I had that as ready reference). However, that's not my question.

Comment: How do you want to syntactically use the result? Like this? `t[0] = whatever;` If so, then it just needs to be a plain older pointer, not a reference.

Comment: You can use references with C-style arrays like in the linked example. This is pretty much the only way to do it. But the larger truth is that you shouldn't use C-style arrays *at all*.

Comment: The correct syntax is `std::vector<T> t(size);`. Why do you need an alternate syntax?

Comment: @downvoters, I don't know why am I getting string of downvotes here. This question was never asked before, and this question seems perfectly valid. Is there anything else which is driving you to downvote ? (without any comment)

Comment: @Bo, I am not following you. I am not asking about `vector<>`. Wanted to know if is there any syntax for reference to `new[]`; I don't want to use `vector<>`.

Comment: @iammilind - I think the downvoters **are** commenting right here. There is a simple C++ way of doing this, but you want to find an obscure and nearly impossible way of doing it instead. That's not a good question, IMO.

Comment: @Bo, there are many such questions asked which doesn't have real solution. But I don't see downvotes for them; may be I am not lucky enough. Moreover, I am asking it syntactically to be informed about it. I have already mentioned in my question, that this is not related to coding practice.

Comment: @iammilind - Even if the question is well formulated, it can be kind of bad anyway. In this case I find that the answer (if you get a correct one) will be totally uninteresting to me, because I will never use it. That makes this a non-good entry for a Q&A site. Thus a downvote from me. Others might get away by having such an uninteresting subject line that they are never looked at. End-of-chat.

Answer (score 2):

> It's common to have reference bound to a simple object as,

No, it isn't. That kind of thing is functional, well-defined C++ code. But it is generally bad form. It forces you to later do this:

```
delete &t;
```

This again is functional and well-defined by the specification. But it is terribly ugly and gives the wrong impression about what the code is doing.

> how to relate a reference with the output of new[] ?

It's unnecessary. In C and C++, pointers and arrays are virtually the same thing (technically, arrays automatically are converted to a pointer to the first element, if they need to). So you can do this:

```
T *t = new T[5];
t[4].stuff();
```

Comment: By '[they] are virtually the same thing', you're then saying that they not, in fact, the same thing. And they indeed aren't.

Comment: @Luc Danton: For all practical purposes, they're the same thing.

Comment: `But it is generally bad form`; can you point out some standard reference/material for this ? Bjarne's link I posted in comments don't suggest that.

Comment: Except for the purposes of having a size encoded in the type and well-defined semantics regarding ownership. Those two things are 'practical' I would think.

Comment: @iammilind: The link you posted specifically says not to do that. It's not specifically talking about storing a pointer in a reference, but it's clearly intended to mirror Java-style (which is what it's saying you shouldn't do in C++). If what you are talking about were truly "common", you should have no problem linking to other examples. I've been programming C++ professionally for a decade, and I've never seen anyone do that.